Hacer que animación recorra lo inverso al dejar de hacer hover
Tengo el siguiente código html y css.
Lo que estoy tratando de hacer es que el contenedor hijo que se encuentra ubicado dentro del contenedor padre, se mueva hacia abajo y luego hacia la derecha y luego hacia arriba (todo eso al hacer hover), pero lo que yo quiero es que al dejar de hacer hover el contenedor hijo regrese por el mismo camino que ya recorrió. Lo que he conseguido hasta ahora es que al dejar de hacer hover el contenedor hijo aparezca en su posición inicial y no recorre el camino para su regreso.


.prueba {
  width: 100%;
  height: 35rem;
  padding: 2em;
  background-color: darkblue;
  display: flex;
  &:hover .prueba-hijo {
    animation: mover 5s linear;
  }
  .prueba-hijo {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blueviolet;
  }
}

@keyframes mover {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0%) translateY(0%);
  }
  25% {
    transform: translateX(0%) translateY(450%);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(1200%) translateY(450%);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translateX(1200%) translateY(0%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0%) translateY(0%);
  }
}
<div class="prueba">
  <div class="prueba-hijo"></div>
</div>




¿Es css o scss?

Hola! No sé la respuesta a tu problema o si es posible hacerlo sin javascript.. pero tal vez esto que he encontrado te sirva de idea para hacerlo con css: https://app.aluracursos.com/forum/topico-como-seria-hover-out-105793 Con eso he conseguido que haga el camino a la inversa.. pero creo que no es exactamente lo que tu pides: https://jsfiddle.net/xgcdh0sk/

gracias por tu ayuda, voy a probarlo.

agrega el .prueba:not(:hover)


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .prueba {
            width: 100%;
            height: 35rem;
            padding: 2em;
            background-color: darkblue;
            display: flex;
        }

        .prueba:hover .prueba-hijo {
            animation: mover 5s linear forwards;
        }

        .prueba:not(:hover) .prueba-hijo {
            animation: retroceder 5s linear forwards;
        }

        .prueba-hijo {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            background-color: blueviolet;
        }

        @keyframes mover {
            0% {
                transform: translateX(0%) translateY(0%);
            }
            25% {
                transform: translateX(0%) translateY(450%);
            }
            50% {
                transform: translateX(1200%) translateY(450%);
            }
            75% {
                transform: translateX(1200%) translateY(0%);
            }
            100% {
                transform: translateX(0%) translateY(0%);
            }
        }

        @keyframes retroceder {
            0% {
                transform: translateX(0%) translateY(0%);
            }
            25% {
                transform: translateX(1200%) translateY(0%);
            }
            50% {
                transform: translateX(1200%) translateY(450%);
            }
            75% {
                transform: translateX(0%) translateY(450%);
            }
            100% {
                transform: translateX(0%) translateY(0%);
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="prueba">
        <div class="prueba-hijo"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>




Bienvenido a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour]. Edité tu respuesta para poner el código dentro de un snippet, lo que permite ejecutarlo aquí dentro del  navegador en la propia respuesta (se hace con el botón <>). Por otro lado, las respuestas que tienen solo código tienden a considerarse de mala calidad, no estaría mal agregar una explicación, que puede ser breve, de cómo tu código resuelve el problema planteado en la pregunta. (aunque al ejecutarlo me parece que no es lo que el AP busca).
